# ReactDOM render -> DOMParser -> querySelectorAll -> returning null

Tags: reactjs, domparser, react-dom, selectors-api

```
const temp = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(component, temp);
const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
  temp.innerHTML,
  'text/html'
);
parsed.querySelectorAll(selector); // <- returns null rather than NodeList
```

^ There is an obscure use-case in my app, centered around needing to render the full tree of a component and query it for certain css classes for diffing against a subset of rules in external stylesheets.

Don't judge! :-)

I *think* I'm doing the above in a manner that I could reasonably expect to give me a proper result but clearly I'm missing something.

Comment: I created a simple example that worked fine with the dummy data I made.  What are `component` and `selector`?  Those are the only things that could be different from the simple test case I created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const temp = document.createElement('div');
ReactDOM.render(component, temp, () => {
  const parsed = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
    temp.innerHTML,
    'text/html'
  );
  const selected = parsed.querySelectorAll(selector);
});
```

As with many such bugs, this one came down to a race condition. The render was taking long enough that the first argument for parseFromString was not available synchronously. Using the optional callback for ReactDOM.render fixed this.